# select records expiring within the next 30 days - sql statement

Tags: java, date, derby

data type: `timestamp`
column name: `dlExpiryDate`

```
SELECT * 
  FROM QUALIFICATION  
 WHERE dlExpiryDate >= NOW() 
   AND dlExpiryDate < NOW() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```

Tried numerous amounts of queries to get the answer but its not working. Anyone got a answer to solve this. Got an example I tried above but it doesnt work. 
Printed out the stacktrace:

> Severe:   java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error: Encountered
>   "1" at line 1, column 93.     at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.executeQuery(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.jsp.viewQualification_jsp._jspService(viewQualification_jsp.java:105)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Syntax error: Encountered "1"
>   at line 1, column 93.     at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.flowExecute(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.executeQueryX(Unknown
>   Source)   ... 36 more

Anyone got an answer to this please? Thanks

Comment: Stacktrace **clearly** shows that you are using ***Derby***, not MySQL, so stop trying to use MySQL syntax!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Time zone

Be aware that the [`TIMESTAMP`](https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/rrefsqlj27620.html) type in Derby is akin to the SQL-standard type `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` (at least it seems that way, the documentation is poorly written). Meaning, that type lacks any concept of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). As such, this type does *not* represent a specific moment, a point on the timeline. Instead, it represents *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours, the range of time zones around the globe.

For example, if you stored noon on the 23rd of January 2019, we do not know if you meant noon in Tokyo Japan, or hours earlier when noon in Kolkata India. Or maybe you meant hours later, noon in Paris France. Or still more hours later, when noon arrives in Montréal Québec. Such a value in this type would mean noon on the 23rd *anywhere*, for any of many moments over a range of 26-27 hours.

So it **makes no sense to do a query** on this type when comparing to now, the current moment.

But…

If you have been handling the time zone in your app, and pretending that all the values in the database are of a certain time zone, use that zone when capturing the current moment.

## `ZonedDateTime`

In the *java.time* classes, we use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) to represent a moment in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;  // Capture the current moment as seen in the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone).
```

## Discarding valuable zone/offset info with `LocalDateTime`

We can strip away the time zone information, leaving only a date and time-of-day in a [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) object.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = zdt.toLocalDateTime()
```

## Start-of-day

If searching for a month, you likely want to start at the beginning of the day. For a moment, we would let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day, as a day does not always start at 00:00 because of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). But with `LocalDateTime` lacking zone/offset, we cannot account for such anomalies. So we will just go with 00:00.

```
LocalDateTime ldtStartOfDay = ldt.with( LocalTime.MIN ) ;
```

## Date-time math

To add your month, we can do date-time math using `plus…` and `minus…` methods.

```
LocalDateTime ldtMonthLater = ldtStartOfDay.plusMonths() ;
```

## SQL placeholders

Pass these values to replace the placeholders in your SQL in a prepared statement.

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM QUALIFICATION  
WHERE dlExpiryDate >= ?
AND dlExpiryDate < ?
;
```

## JDBC 4.2

As of JDBC 4.2 and later, we can directly exchange *java.time* objects with a database using `setObject` & `getObject`. No need to ever use the terrible legacy classes such as `java.sql.Timestamp`.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 1 , ldtStartOfDay) ;
myPreparedStatement.setObject( 2 , ldtMonthLater) ;
```

When retrieving.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDateTime.class ) ;
```

## Consider other databases

You might want to consider using other databases. Oracle stopped bundling Derby as [*Java DB*](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) because it was found to be unsuitable for production use.

If you want an open-source database written in Java, I would suggest the [H2 Database Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H2_(DBMS)), suitable for both embedded use as well as a server. If you want an open-source database server built for heavy-duty enterprise-quality work, I suggest [Postgres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL).

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do that query in a database-agnostic way, resolve the 2 dates in Java code and supply them using a `PreparedStatement`.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
String sql = "SELECT *" +
              " FROM QUALIFICATION" +
             " WHERE dlExpiryDate >= ?" +
               " AND dlExpiryDate < ?";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql)) {
    stmt.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(today));
    stmt.setDate(2, java.sql.Date.valueOf(today.plusMonths(1)));
    try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Depending on the JDBC driver (e.g. not Microsoft), you can also use `setObject`.

```
stmt.setObject(1, today);
stmt.setObject(2, today.plusMonths(1));
```

Comment: Would this still work considering the column being timestamp?

Comment: @unknown If you want time-of-day included in the boundaries, use `LocalDateTime` and `java.sql.Timestamp` instead.